# Counts and left join not working right

Tags: count, sum, left-join, max

Trying to do a count on these lines COUNT(engineerName) AS engineerCount,
                    Count(managerName) as managerCount,
                    Count(isContractor) as contractorCount
but it keeps returning the same numbers for all three. So I'm trying to add a Where for each one, Example Count(isContractor where isContractor = 'yes') as contractorCount but getting errors please help, thank you.

```
<?php


        clASs EfficiencyController extends DooController
        {


        function getEfficiency(){

        include './protected/config/db.conf.php';
        Doo::db()->setDb($dbconfig, 'local_network');


        $Vendor = ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") ? $_POST['Vendor'] : $_GET['Vendor'];
        $date   =   ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") ? $_POST['date'] : $_GET['date'];
        $level   =  ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") ? $_POST['level'] : $_GET['level'];
            switch($level) {
            case "Region":
            case "area":
                $Market99="";
                break;
            default:
                $Market99=$level;
                break;

        }
    {
        //
        // LUCENT,NORTEL
        //


        $query = " SELECT 
                  DayKey,
                Market99,
                Region,
                areaName,
                Sum(Total_Sites) as totalCount,
                Max(engineerCount) AS engineerCount,
                Max(managerCount) AS managerCount,
                Max(contractorCount) AS contractorCount,
                SC_Type,
                Sum(Total_Carriers),
                Sum(Total_Sectors),
                Vendor 
                FROM
                network.envEquipSummaryConfig a
            Left Join
            (SELECT 
                market,
                    areaName,
                    COUNT(engineerName) AS engineerCount,
                    Count(managerName) as managerCount,
                    Count(isContractor) as contractorCount
            FROM
                employee.employees
            GROUP BY market
            ORDER BY COUNT(market) DESC) b ON a.Market99 = b.market
            Where
            a.DayKey <= \"$date\" and a.Vendor = \"$Vendor\" 
            Group By Market99 asc";


            switch($level) {
                case "region":
                        $query = $query. " order by region ASC";
                        break;
                        case "area":
                        $query = $query. " order by areaName ASC";
                        break;
                default;
                        $query = $query. " order by Market99 ASC";
                        break;  

            }

        }
        //echo $query; exit;    

        $this->setContentType('xml');
        $result = Doo::db()->fetchAll($query);





        printf("<root>\n");
        if(count($result) > 0)
        foreach($result AS $row) {


                    printf("\t<data>\n");
                printf("\t\t<date>%s</date>\n",$row["DayKey"]);
                printf("\t\t<vName>%s</vName>\n",$row["Vendor"]);
                printf("\t\t<location>%s</location>\n",$row["Market99"]);
                printf("\t\t<toCount>%s</toCount>\n",$row["totalCount"]);
                printf("\t\t<enCount>%s</enCount>\n",$row["engineerCount"]);
                printf("\t\t<mnCount>%s</mnCount>\n",$row["managerCount"]);
                printf("\t\t<cnCount>%s</cnCount>\n",$row["contractorCount"]);


                printf("\t</data>\n");

        }
      printf("</root>\n");

    }
}   

?>
```

Comment: If your question is about the SQL, you could edit it to remove all of the PHP noise, and replace it with the schema of your tables, some sample data, and the output you're trying to obtain. You could also be more specific than "getting errors", since we can't see your screen from here and don't know what "errors" means. It would be much more useful in trying to help you, and would probably get you an answer much more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  market,
  areaName,
  COUNT(engineerName) AS engineerCount,
  Count(managerName) as managerCount,
  Count(isContractor) as contractorCount
FROM
  employee.employees
GROUP BY market
```

should be

`Group By market,areaName` at a guess.

Which is all it can be seeing as you've provided next to no useful information.